# Comparing values of a generic type in generic functions in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

The following function

```
def compare[T] (o1:T, o2:T):Boolean = {
   o1 > o2
}
```

will not compile, because `value > is not a member of type parameter T`

Defining the parameters to be of type `AnyVal` also does not work, and the compiler gives a similar error.

However, the function can only be called with values of type `String` and `Long`, which do support `>`.

What is the recomended soultion to write such a function?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Ordering` type class like so:

```
def compare[T](o1: T, o2: T)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]) = ord.gt(o1, o2)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `>` operator you can use **view bound** with `Ordered[T]`

```
def compare[T <% Ordered[T]] (o1:T, o2:T):Boolean = {
  o1 > o2
}
```

There are good examples in scala docs.

http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-and-view-bounds.html

or you can do it with implicit parameter cause view bounds are deprecated now:

```
def  compare[T](o1: T, o2: T)(implicit ev: T => Ordered[T]): Boolean = {
  o1 < o2
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid explicitly mentioning an implicit parameter, but also avoid using the now-deprecated view bounds, you can do it with context bounds like this, by defining a type alias:

```
type OrderedView[T] = T => Ordered[T]

def compare[T: OrderedView](o1: T, o2: T) = {
  o1 > o2
}
```

This pattern doesn't seem to be very well-documented, unfortunately - I found it on [a post in the scala-internals mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-internals/hNow9MvAi6Q/HgrjWDaF1mIJ) when trying to work out how to implement the "enrich my library" pattern without using context bounds.

Answer (score 1):

View bounds are deprecated, you should not use them, you can however use context bounds. This will give you implicit access to an ordering instance and you can use the compare method:

```
def compare[T: Ordering] (o1:T, o2:T):Boolean = {
  val ord = implicitly[Ordering[T]] 
  ord.compare(o1, o2) > 0
}
```

Now if you have to do this a lot directly using the operators is much nicer of course. Ordering directly provides an implicit conversion, that you can just import locally:

```
def compare[T: Ordering] (o1:T, o2:T):Boolean = {
  val ord = implicitly[Ordering[T]] 
  import ord.mkOrderingOps
  o1 > o2
}
```